# Django with cx_Oracle, calling PL/SQL function is taking lot of time

Tags: python, django, oracle, cx-oracle

I have PL/SQL function defined in oracle database. When I call it in "**Toad For Oracle**" using following statement
"`select ccl_bal(1,2,0) from dual`"
it take hardly 2 seconds. But when I call it from **Django 3.2** it takes lot of time, almost 5 minuts. I am using **cx_oracle oracle library 8.1.0** and Here is my code.
`result=connection.cursor().callfunc("ccl_bal",int,[1, 2, 0])`
Any help??

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/578

Answer (score 0):

This can very well be caused by different optimizer settings in the session. You can compare by checking:
select value from v$parameter where name='optimizer_mode';